# How to filter the return values of a method with AspectJ?

Tags: java, methods, annotations, aspectj, signature

I would like to filter return values of methods which have a `@Filter` annotation and return a `Collection`, an `Array` or a `Map` by a certain predicate.

I tried something like:

```
    @Pointcut("execution(@example.annotations.Filter * *(..)) "
            + "&& @annotation(filter) ")
    public void filterOperation(final Filter filter) {
        /* ... */
    }
```

But I get syntax errors if I add `execution((java.util.Collection+ || java.util.Map+) * * (..))` to the PointCut above.

How would a solution look like, preferable one where I could error out if some method was annotated with `@Filter` but would not return a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to use `execution((java.util.Collection+ || java.util.Map+) *.* (..))`?

Or you can use:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@example.annotations.Filter java.util.Collection+ || java.util.Map+ *(..)) "
        + "&& @annotation(filter) ")
public void filterOperation(final Filter filter) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You can handle return value the following way:

```
@AfterReturning(value="filterOperation(filter)", returning="collection")
public void handlingReturnValue(final Filter filter, Object collection) {
    System.out.println(collection);
}
```

But I suppose it will be better to use separate advices for `Map`s and `Collection`s:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@Filter java.util.Collection+ *(..)) "
        + "&& @annotation(filter) ")
public void filterCollection(final Filter filter) {
    /* ... */
}

@Pointcut("execution(@Filter java.util.Map+ *(..)) "
        + "&& @annotation(filter) ")
public void filterMap(final Filter filter) {
    /* ... */
}

@AfterReturning(value="filterCollection(filter)", returning="collection")
public void handlingReturnCollection(final Filter filter, Collection collection) {
    System.out.println(collection);
}

@AfterReturning(value="filterMap(filter)", returning="map")
public void handlingReturnMap(final Filter filter, Map map) {
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: Now it says `"name pattern" expected`

Comment: It compiles now, but how do I actually access the returned value?

Comment: I've modified my answer once again :)

Comment: @soc you need an `@Around` or `@AfterReturning` advice.